# Комментарии в файле настроек пользователя в sublime-text-3 удаляются

Tags: sublime-text-3

Комментарии в файле настроек пользователя в sublime-text-3 удаляются. Как отключить эту фишку?

Записываю комментарии для себя, но при очередном изменении настроек или установке нового плагина эти комментарии удаляются.

Comment: Sublime Text Build 3176

Comment: Вот минутный ролик про то что я имею ввиду http://rgho.st/private/89Tdz7SNN/87fc9c4734c415ab6beb427a35d97aa7

Comment: Так это же `JSON -файл`, в нем не могут быть комментарии!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  `JSON -файл` с комментами невалидный

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход, это конечно не совсем комментария но в моем случае не плохое решение.

```
"": "Могут ли комментарии использоваться в JSON?",
"#": "Могут ли комментарии использоваться в JSON?",
"//": "Могут ли комментарии использоваться в JSON?",
"_comment": "Могут ли комментарии использоваться в JSON?",
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json/244858#244858)

Comment: Голь на выдумки хитра)))))

Comment: Но все равно это кривой костыль. В голове файла эти "комментария" еще сохраняются, а в других местах после сохранения файла sublime удаляет. Так что затея не удачная ...и не актуальная уже